# selenium chrome attach default profile

Tags: python, selenium, pyqt

i am using python ana selenium, to automate some process, but couldnt attached selenium to default chrome profile
i tried with,

```
capability = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/hib',capability)
```

of course, i started, chromedriver first, and also tried with,

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.chrome.service as service
service = service.Service('./chromedriver')
service.start()
capabilities = {'chrome.binary': '/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome'}
driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url, capabilities)
driver.get('http://www.google.com/xhtml');
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
driver.quit()
```

this causes, selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: u'Could not find Chrome binary at:

and also tried with,

```
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver")
```

this works, but not default profile, and also wonder to know, how to open new window or new tab with this ?

thanks.

Comment: Well does the chrome binary live in: `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome`? That's what you are telling it!

Comment: thanks for your reply, according to this, https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver yes it's there.

Answer (score 2):

Don't just copy/paste something straight off the website! Have a look into that folder yourself, does it have anything in it?! My guess is no. This is why when you leave that bit off, it works fine, because it's looking for Chrome where it should exist!

Any way, more to the point you are using it wrongly!

If you want to give Selenium a different profile to use for Chrome, then you need to use the `options` class:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/py/selenium/webdriver/chrome/options.py

You want the `add_argument` function.

Why?

This is because to give Chrome another profile to use, you need to launch Chrome with a specific command line (specifically `--user-data-dir`):

http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory

The `add_argument` function exposes the ability to add command line switches.

So if you use the `add_argument` function, Selenium will simply pass whatever you give it, down to Chrome as being part of it's command line switches.

Answer (score 0):

To find out where your chrome profile is located start chrome and type

```
chrome://version
```

in the address bar. Under "Profile Path:" you'll see the location of the profile you're currently using. For example:

```
~:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
```